# How to display multiple images from local directory in a QML Project?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to display multiple images from a local directory in a QML Project. I'm a newbie in QT programming.

I'm using this code, this is code is running, but no image display. I'm using Ubuntu.

```
ListView {

    width: 400;
    height: 500

    FolderListModel {
        id: folderModel
        nameFilters: ["*.jpg"]

        folder: "/home/pc/jpeg_serial_capture/Capture_Image/04-02-2019/"
    }

    Component {
        id: fileDelegate
        Column {
            Image {
                width: 150; height: 150
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                smooth: true
                source: folderModel.folder + "/home/pc/jpeg_serial_capture/Capture_Image/04-02-2019/" + fileName
            }
            Text { text: fileName }
        }
    }

    model: folderModel
    delegate: fileDelegate
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the url with prefix `file://`, instead of concatenating the file name you should use `fileURL`:

```
ListView {
    width: 400;
    height: 500
    FolderListModel {
        id: folderModel
        nameFilters: ["*.jpg"]
        folder: "file:///home/pc/jpeg_serial_capture/Capture_Image/04-02-2019"
    }
    Component {
        id: fileDelegate
        Column {
            Image {
                width: 150; height: 150
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                smooth: true
                source: fileURL
             }
            Text { text: fileName }
        }
    }
    model: folderModel
    delegate: fileDelegate
}
```

Comment: You have to use "file:///" for windows and "files://" for linux.